# Javascript append html tags before for loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following code below, where I am trying to create a `ul` tag, and inside it a for loop to dynamically create `li` elements. A separate closing `ul` tag is created after the loop is completed.

The code works. Except for the problem that the code does not run in order like I want it to. The `ul` tags are closed before the for loop can be processed into the page, resulting in the html looking more like:

`<ul></ul><li>0</li><li>1</li>...`

```js
var insidethediv = document.getElementById("insidethediv");
var numero = 5;

insidethediv.innerHTML = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
insidethediv.innerHTML += "<li>"+i+"</li>";
}
insidethediv.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

```html
<div id="insidethediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning directly to `innerHTML` is a bad idea here. `innerHTML` expects a complete html fragment, i.e. all open tags should be closed. But here you are assigning to a partial html fragment while you are building it. Try to create the complete html first and then assign it to `innerHTML`, e.g. like so:

```
var insidethediv = document.getElementById("insidethediv");
var numero = 5;

var s = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    s += "<li>"+i+"</li>";
}
s += "</ul>";
insidethediv.innerHTML = s;
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use document.createElement(*tag name*) and *Element*.append(*created element reference*) functions. In this way we are able to manipulate each individual <li> tag (such as assign different colors) and render the HTML tags dynamically instead of jamming everything into a string then insert it as an innerHTML element.

```js
var insidethediv = document.getElementById("insidethediv");
var numero = 5;

var ul_element = document.createElement("ul");
insidethediv.append(ul_element);

var li_element;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    li_element = document.createElement("li");
    ul_element.append(li_element);
    li_element.innerHTML = i;
}
```

```html
<div id="insidethediv"></div>
```